# Express API returning an unwanted "data" section in my GET all requests

Tags: node.js, express

I'm currently building a rest API and I'm having an unexpected output when I make a /GET request.

When i make a get request to the API, it returns

```
{ 
  data: {
    [{myExpectedObjects},{myExpectedObjects}]
  }
}
```

however, I'm expecting my get request to return just the array of objects. Below is the code im using to accomplish the rest calls

Create controller

```
const create = (req, res) => {
    let dataModel = generateModel(genericDataFromReq);

    dataModel = new dataModel({
      genericData,
      specificData,
    });

    dataModel.save().then((data) => {
      res.status(201).send(data);
    }, (e) => {
      res.status(500).send(e);
    });
  }
};
```

get all controller

```
const list = (req, res) => {
  const dataModel = generateModel(dataToGet);

  dataModel.find().then((data) => {
    if (data.length === 0) {
      res.status(404).send('failed');
    } else {
      res.status(200).send({ data });
    }
  }, (e) => {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  });
};
```

generate data model

```
function generateModel(dbCollectionName) {
  try {
    return generateDataModel(dbCollectionName);
  } catch (e) {
    return mongoosee.model(`${dbCollectionName}`);
  }
}
```

I know the code is a bit unconventional but I've set up a generic rest API to take in different types of requests and I found this solution to be the best way of doing this.

Any ideas on why my get all request is tacking on a "data" section before my array of objects (which is what I'm actually interest in)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is in this line:

```
else {
  res.status(200).send({ data });
}
```

When you put curly braces around a variable, it creates a key-value pair where the key is the name of the variable and the value is the value of the variable. So get rid of the curly braces and it should work as you expect. See the parts that mention this ES2015 notation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer